# Vector questions about finding magnitudes, dot products, and angles.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am given the following problem:

> Let $\Vert \overrightarrow{a}\Vert = 3$ , $\Vert
>  \overrightarrow{b}\Vert = 2$ and $\angle
>  \left(\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b}\right) = 60^\circ$. Find $\Vert
>  \overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$, $\Vert
>  \overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$, $\overrightarrow{a} \cdot
>  \overrightarrow{b}$ and $\angle
>  \left(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b},
>  \overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\right)$.

I was able to evaluate $\Vert \overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$ and $\Vert \overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$ through cosine Law:

$$
\Vert \overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert = \sqrt{19}\\
\Vert \overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert = \sqrt{7}
$$

I am stuck on the next step. If I could evaluate the angle between $\Vert \overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$ and $\Vert \overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert$ I could finish the exercise. If somebody could give me a hint, I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Aren't you given $\theta$?  What's the $60^\circ$?

Comment: @tilper yes you are correct. I just rephrased my last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\vec x\cdot \vec y = \|\vec x\| \cdot \|\vec y\| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.  Use this fact with $\vec x = \vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec y = \vec a - \vec b$.

You already have $\|\vec x\|$ and $\|\vec y\|$.  To find $\vec x \cdot \vec y$, recall the distributivity of the dot product:
$$
  (\vec a + \vec b) \cdot (\vec a - \vec b) = \vec a \cdot \vec a - \vec a \cdot \vec b + \vec b \cdot \vec a - \vec b \cdot \vec b = \|a\|^2 - \|b\|^2
$$